# How to resize video after completed video in iphone without click on done button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, video

When I click on video in iphone it automatically resize in full window. but when video completed we need to click on done button to resize it.

I want like when video completed it will automatically resize after completed video without click on done button. how can I do this ?

Please help me

Comment: Kindly read about on how to control or listen on video events by js https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html